# Webservice doesn't throw correct ERemotableException for SOAP faults, depending on order or presence of class registry

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, delphi-xe

I imported a WCF service in Delphi (XE) using the WSDL import wizard, and the service uses specific faults to communicate exceptions. Everything is working fine, except that Delphi doesn't throw the specific ERemotableException descendant for faults.

In the import, proxies have been generated for all the faults, and every fault comes in two classes:
One descending from `ERemotableException`, and one descending from `TRemotable`:

```
  UnknownEntityFault2 = class(TRemotable)
    // ...stuff...
  end;

  UnknownEntityFault = class(ERemotableException)
   // ...stuff...
  end;
```

and they they get registered in the initialization section:

```
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(UnknownEntityFault2, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Kraan.Probis.Synchronisatie.Service', 'UnknownEntityFault2', 'UnknownEntityFault');

  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(UnknownEntityFault, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Kraan.Probis.Synchronisatie.Service', 'UnknownEntityFault');
```

Without changes, if I call the webservice, a `ERemotableException` will be caught:

```
  try 
    service.DoSomething();
  except
    on E: UnknownEntityFault do begin
      ShowMessage('UnknownEntityFault');
    end;
    on E: ERemotableException do begin
      ShowMessage('ERemotableException');   <--- Enters this catch block
    end;
  end;
```

If I either don't register the `UnknownEntityFault2` class (the one descending from `TRemotable`). or if I register that class **after** I register `UnknownEntityFault`, a `UnknownEntityFault` will be thrown:

```
  try 
    service.DoSomething();
  except
    on E: UnknownEntityFault do begin
      ShowMessage('UnknownEntityFault'); <--- Enters this catch block
    end;
    on E: ERemotableException do begin
      ShowMessage('ERemotableException');   
    end;
  end;
```

Is there way to

- Make sure the class descending from `TRemotable` for the fault is
  not generated?

or

- Control the order of registering the classes?

I can of course move or delete those entries my self, but it's a manual step that I would prefer to avoid, and actually that I shouldn't **have** to do myself in order for things to work properly.

Comment: Sounds like your WSDL is broken and Delphi doesn't recognize those as execption types. Did you check if the `Import Fault Types` setting was enabled during import of the WSDL? My guess is these type(s) should have been registered with the `InvRegistry.RegisterException` method.

Comment: "Import Fault Types" is checked, and it actually imports them (see the definition of UnknownEntityFault, which derives from ERemotableException). It's the 2nd class it also creates for it (UnknownEntityFault2) that causes problems. If I register UnknownEntityFault2, and register *before* the exception class (UnknownEntityFault), it doesn't work. If I either don't register it or move it *after* I register the exception class (UnknownEntityFault), it works.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the WSDL. Java understands it, .NET understands, and Delphi understands it, except that the throwing of the correct exception in Delphi depends on either NOT registering UnknownEntityFault2 (which derives from TRemotable), or registering UnknownEntityFault2 AFTER I register UnknownEntityFault.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a similar problem (Delphi XE) and one possible solution to the problem without editing the generated code from the WSDL is to do the following:

```
RemClassRegistry.UnRegisterXSClass(UnknownEntityFault2);
```

Obviously this needs to be done after the initialization of the generated unit is done.

Another way, which I think is better is to make a change to the WCF Service and specify a name in the FaultContract, this will then name the ERemotableException to the name of the FaultContract and the TRemotable to the class.

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(UnknownEntityFault), Name = "NamedFault")]
```

This will create the ERemotableException as NamedFault and the TRemotable will be UnknownEntityFault